# Liquid in Lungs?

Tags: lungs, swallow-swallowing, hypochondria

So, here I was, eating and drinking in the car because my family didn't have time to stop and eat (we're on vacation) and, anyways, while I was swallowing my strawberry hi-c, I felt this odd, tickly feeling in the back of my throat that made me twitch. I did not know wether that was the cough reflex or not, so I ignored it. But as that liquid went down, however, I couldn't sworn I felt something cold trickle down my chest area (both left and right side) Afterwards, my upper chest area DOES hurt a little (not unbearable) and I'm not wheezing or anything..(not yet!) But I'm quite frightened, nonethless. Please note: I am 16 yr old hypocondriac who has a severe swallowing phobia. Can anyone please help me? I really don't feel like begging my parents to take me to the hsptl.while we're on vacation...I want them to enjoy it without having to calm their anxious daughter.

Comment: Questions requesting personal medical advice are off-topic here, to avoid closure, please try to edit the question so that it is generic. Nobody here can properly address your health issues. Such questions should be taken to your personal physician who can examine you and access your full medical records. For more information, please see this [meta post](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/56/are-personal-medical-advice-questions-on-topic-here/258).